# Visual Studio Extension Error List ContextMenu

Tags: mef, vsix, vspackage

We are using a Visual Studio extension to do some checks on a custom XML file. Errors that are detected are displayed in the Error List.

Is it possible to extend the context menu of an errortask item in the Error List of Visual studio? We want to add automatic correction functionality to our extension.

Answer (score 1):

There was an example of adding custom menu items for FxCop:

http://vsxexperience.net/2011/06/28/extending-fxcop-rules-with-fixing-ability/

You can follow the sample code in:

http://stylecopfixer.codeplex.com/